# Python While Loop does not execute

Tags: python

The program wants me to do this: If the user gives the number 4, the program calculates the sum 0+1+2+3, if 7, the calculation is 0+1+2+3+4+5+6.
Example output:

> > > Give a number: 3
> > >       The sum was: 3

Give a number: 5
The sum was: 10

> > > 

This is my code

```
num = int(input("Give a number:"))
i = 0
total = 0;
while i < num.lenghth:
    total += i;
    i++;
    break
```

But the program doesn't run

Comment: use `range` ex `print(sum(range(5)))`

Comment: Is `.lenghth` a typo? Does `int.length` even exist?

Comment: The code you show should give an error (since integers doesn't have a `length` attribute, which you misspell anyway). When creating a [mcve] make sure it replicates the behavior or the error you're actually asking about. Then copy-paste it into the question.

Comment: I think the program runs but has no output, right? You should print the total after the while loop. One more thing, you shouldn't have that break inside the loop. That's breaking the loop.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
num = int(input("Give a number:"))

total = 0;
for i in range(0, num):
    total += i;
print(total)
```

the for-loop with range could be sexier then a while loop. The range gives the range of your index i, where it should run over.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `variable++` in `Python`.

That being said these solutions would work for you:

```
num = int(input("Give a number:"))
i = 0
total = 0;
while i < num:
    total += i
    i += 1
print(total)
```

Or

```
num = int(input("Give a number:"))
print(sum(range(num)))
```